# sql: how create third column and move 2° result with same id

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

i have this situation

| id | name | barcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aaa | 123123 |
| 123 | aaa | 231233233312 |
| 444 | bbb | 1238882 |
| 444 | bbb | 43434344 |
| 555 | ccc | 4543443 |
| 453 | ddd | 123 |

i wish to move the second result with the same id to a third column:

| id | name | barcode1 | barcode2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aaa | 123123 | 231233233312 |
| 444 | bbb | 1238882 | 43434344 |
| 555 | ccc | 4543443 | empty |
| 453 | ddd | 123 | empty |

can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` with `count`, `min` and `max` aggregate functions as follows:

```
Select id, name,
       Min(barcode) as barcode_1,
       Case when count(1) > 1 then max(barcode) end as barcode_2 
From your_table
Group by id, name
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question to make sense, you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows. Let me assume that you have such row, and that is called `ordering_id`.

Then, you can use window functions to enumerate the rows of each group, and conditional aggregation to pivot:

```
select id, name, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then barcode end) as barcode1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then barcode end) as barcode2
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by id, name order by ordering_id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by id, name
```